# Access internal host from a subdomain of an external dns

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, port-forwarding, internal-dns

This image contains the topology I want to make work.

I have a linux server that is used for hosting websites and also routing for our internal network. How can I access the internal server that hosts the team foundation server from outside from a domain like teamfoundation.example.com.

The parent domain is hosted on the linux machine, is there a way to NAT the dns queries to the windows server?

```
                                               |LINUX SERVER| example.com
                                                     |
                                                     |
 Windows Server(teamfoundation.example.com)   _______|_________SWITCH Internal Network
```

Comment: You can't NAT DNS queries. Unfortunately I'm not sure I understand your question very well.

Comment: Accessing a Website via HTTP protocol and DNS resolution are two separate concerns. First decide on which external Socket (IP + TCP Port) the teamfoundation website should be available and how to traverse the NAT. Then decide the external hostname. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the reply..... ok i will  point out the things it might be confusing. From what i understand from Thomas i must nat my internal server to  externalip:portNumber, and then make my dns entries to that Ip. Thanks Thomas i think i have the problem almoust solved.

Comment: @Mihai It seems you are on the right path. I think you should then write your insights in the question as well so that it can be helpful for others, too. I guess you can write your own answer now? If not, let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: You're trying to hit an internal website from outside the network.

The DNS for the domain needs to be publicly resolvable to the outside IP that you want to use.  Then you NAT that IP at the external device to your internal IP.

For Example if you have a Class C IP Block (1.1.1.x), and you choose to use 1.1.1.25 for your teamfoundation.example.com site, while the internal IP is 10.1.1.25.

In this case you set up teamfoundation.example.com with an A Record on your nameserver that points to 1.1.1.25. Then in your external facing device you NAT 1.1.1.25 to 10.1.1.25.

Depending on what the site is you may have security concerns such as only allowing by certain IP ranges, requiring a password to access the site, etc. but that's a separate point.